# Vuejs onMounted vs watch ref

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to call a function that takes an `HTMLElement` as a parameter.  The element in question is rendered as part of my page template so I need to wait for it to actually be in the DOM.  I think there are two possible ways to wait for this element to be visible:

1. Watching a `ref`

```html
<template><div ref="el"></div></template>
<script>
import {ref, watch} from "vue";
import {exampleFunction} from "example";
export default {
    setup() {
        const el = ref();
        watch(el, (newEl, oldEl) => {
            if (typeof oldEl === "undefined") // Only call function once
                exampleFunction(newEl);
        });
        return {el}
    }
}
</script>
```

2. Using `onMounted`

```html
<template><div id="el" ref="el1"></div></template>
<script>
import {onMounted, ref} from "vue";
import {exampleFunction} from "example";
export default {
    setup() {
        const el1 = ref();
        onMounted(() => {
            let el2 = document.querySelector("#el"); 
            exampleFunction(el2);
            // OR exampleFunction(el1.value);
        });
        return {el1}
    }
}
</script>
```

As far as I can tell, both of these provide a reference to the element once it actually exists in the DOM.  Is there a reason why one of these would be preferred over the other?  Am I missing something about how either of these two situations would function?  Finally, is there some reason that an entirely different solution would be more appropriate?

Comment: less usage of `watch`  might be better for performance? Is there any reason to keep watching if only to be used once? Might be expensive to have a watch hanging around that does only one thing.

Comment: That's a good point, hadn't considered resource impacts

Comment: Why not just use `this.$refs.el` in mounted. no need to watch.

Comment: @MichaelMano I mean, sure, you could use a ref in the onMounted call, however, I don't think that's terribly different than `document.querySelector`.  That said, watch vs. mounted is basically my entire question!

Comment: Yeah i understood your question, was more a question of my own. And yes watching the el is kinda pointless since your only need it once. mounted. also `$refs` has better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your example there is no difference between the two. You can even use `onMounted` with ref instead of calling `document.querySelector`.

But I would generally prefer `watch` or `watchEffect` for waiting for things to be become a certain state. The `onMounted` approach only works when you do not have conditional rendering in your template (e.g. v-if).

Performance wise I would consider there is no real difference. Sure, there is a watch, but your ref only changes once in its entire lifecycle. (And if for some reason if el ref does change, onMounted will not work neither)

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to look like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="el"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    let el = document.querySelector("#el");

    exampleFunction(el);

    return {el}
    }
}
</script>
```

You should also checkout the documentation for Vue Life Cycle Hooks for more information.

Comment: I think your code works the same as OP's second approach, except he is using Vue 3's `setup` option.

Comment: `mounted` is the same thing as `onMounted`.  I'm using the [Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html)